# I cannot install KB 968211 "this update is not applicable to your computer"

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player

I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1, genuinely activated.

I want to install Windows Media Player 12 but it seems I require the "Media Feature Pack". I can't seem to find a good installer. I've tried at least four of them, both 64-bit and 32-bit. I am told:

> This update is not applicable to your computer.

I've searched for a long time but to no avail. Here's one example:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16546

Any ideas how I can get a working Media Feature Pack installed?

Comment: Are you sure you have the N or KN edition of Windows 7?

Comment: I don't have N or KN.. i guess.    So how do i get windows media player 12 for non-N-or-KN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link you posted:

> Windows 7 N and Windows 7 KN editions include the same functionality as Windows 7, except that these versions of Windows do not include Windows Media Player, and related technologies.
>
> End-user customers can enable the media functionality to work properly by installing the Windows Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N and Windows 7 KN (KB968211).

Do you have N or KN?

Comment: How do i determine?  I have neither an N or KN in my Computer > properties

Comment: I imagine you're infering that i have neither N nor KN?   :-p

Comment: Pretty much. I have never seen a N or KN install, so I do not know if it should be displayed along the version number (although I guess so), but this should tell for sure: Go to `Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off` and look for `Media Features`. If it is there, you do not have N or KN.

Comment: Selected this answer because it points out that the misread is N or KN only.. and the correct answer was included in the comments. :)

Answer (score 13):

Go to Control Panel and select Programs and Features.

Select "Turn Windows features on or off".

Under "Media Features" turn on (tick) Windows Media Player.  Press OK.

Comment: yep, i'm dumb... thank you... this did the tick.